# Ruby on Rails 4, Devise, and profile pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, user-profile

I am new to coding, so this is probably a simple question.

I started using RoR about a month ago. Unfortunately, I've hit a bump and can't seem to get over it. I've tried looking at other SO questions for help, but I'm still a novice, so the coding suggestions still look a little foreign to me. I was hoping someone could put things into more novice-friendly terms.

What I want to do is have my website set up a profile for each user that signs up. This would be a private profile that only the user and admins would have access to. After the user signs up/logs in, I'd like for them to be redirected to their profile, where they can edit info like age and weight.

I've spent the last 3 days trying to figure out how to get a profile page created for each new user. I looked at the Devise github readme file, but I'm still stumped.

I've generated a users controller and users view, but I don't even know if I needed to do those steps since I have devise. Any help you guys could give me would be appreciated.

Here's a link to my github page - https://github.com/Thefoodie/PupPics

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Further to Kirti's answer, you'll need to actually have a `profile` to redirect to:

**Models**

```
#app/models/profile.rb
Class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile
    before_create :build_profile #creates profile at user registration
end
```

---

**Schema**

```
profiles
id | user_id | name | birthday | other | info | created_at | updated_at
```

---

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :profiles, only: [:edit]
```

---

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb
def edit
   @profile = Profile.find_by user_id: current_user.id
   @attributes = Profile.attribute_names - %w(id user_id created_at updated_at)
end
```

---

**View**

```
#app/views/profiles/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
    <% @attributes.each do |attr| %>
       <%= f.text_field attr.to_sym %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You'll then need to employ the [`after_sign_in_path`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) stuff Kirti posted

---

**Updated**

Here is the migration you'd use:

```
# db/migrate/[[timestamp]]_create_profiles.rb
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.references :user
      # columns here
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome, I actually had created a user_profiles scaffold that took care of most of that. I wish I could upvote both you and Kirti's answers, but I don't have the rep yet. The site is redirecting user's to their own profile page, now I need to figure out how to put their own personal info on that page.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - hope it helps! You can use the code I made to display the data you need!

Comment: how do you add that schema to the databse?

Comment: Updated answer for you

Answer (score 8):

First you need to setup `after_sign_in_path_for` and `after_sign_up_path_for` for your resource in `ApplicationController` which will direct to the `profile` page. 
Then you need to create a `controller` which will render the `profile` page.

For Example: (Change it according to your requirement)

In `ApplicationController` define the paths

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    profile_path(resource)
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    profile_path(resource)
  end
```

In `ProfilesController`

```
  ## You can skip this action if you are not performing any tasks but,
  ## It's always good to include an action associated with a view.

  def profile

  end
```

Also, make sure you create a `view` for user profile.

Comment: Thank you for the help! When I get more reputation, I'll be sure to come back and upvote this answer.