# Profile model is deleted when I fail to validate on Devise Edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

So, I'm a beginner in RoR4 and I thought I'd go on a practice project. I am using Devise for a User model and I went on to add a Profile model to it like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  before_create :build_profile # Creates profile at user creation
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  ...
end
```

and

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user    
  validates :user_id, presence: true      
end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions', registrations: 'users/registrations' }
resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :destroy]
resources :profiles, only: [:update]

namespace :admin do
  root "base#index"
  resources :users
end

authenticated do
  root to: 'pages#menu', as: :authenticated
end
```

I basically want to allow editing the profile in the same Edit form that Devise generated. So I added this to application_controller:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
...
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u| u.permit(
      :email, 
      :password, 
      :password_confirmation,
      :current_password,
      :name,
      profile_attributes: [:birthday, :phone, :address, :about, :restrictions, :avatar]
      ) 
  end
end
```

and I followed the instructions on [this page on Devise's wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) to restrict requiring the password only on email and password change, as follows:

```
  def update
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)

  successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
    @user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
    else
      # remove the virtual current_password attribute
      # update_without_password doesn't know how to ignore it
      params[:user].delete(:current_password)
      @user.update_without_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
    end

    if successfully_updated
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private

    # check if we need password to update user data
    # ie if password or email was changed
    # extend this as needed
    def needs_password?(user, params)
      user.email != params[:user][:email] ||
        params[:user][:password].present?
    end
```

I then updated the nested form and everything went as expected with until I tried NOT to provide my old password when changing the email or password. I got the notice message but then the `Profile` associated with the `User` just turned to `nil`, and poof, it's gone. Here is the server log message:

```
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"L1i+uV0LFvyVs3xLOMYUJyqeZLnFSWV6R0igyG4+W7E=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Foo Bar1", "profile_attributes"=>{"birthday"=>"", "phone"=>"", "address"=>"", "about"=>"Lorem ipsum dolor", "restrictions"=>"", "avatar"=>"", "id"=>"13"}, "email"=>"user@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Unpermitted parameters: id
  Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = ? ORDER BY "profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = ?  [["id", 13]]
   (13.4ms)  commit transaction
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'user@example.com' AND "users"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('user1') AND "users"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1
```

Any suggestion on what could have gone wrong? how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

Rereading the whole discussion with @RichPeck and @KirtiThorat here, and specifically the server log, I managed to solve the issue of recreating the profile object and deleting the old one by adding the profile ID as one of the permitted parameters in Devise's `:account_update` sanitizer, like so:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u| u.permit(
          :email, 
          :password, 
          :password_confirmation,
          :current_password,
          :name,
          profile_attributes: [:id, :birthday, :phone, :address, :about, :restrictions, :avatar]
          ) 
end
```

I don't know what's the impact of that on security, so I would still appreciate a feedback.

Comment: So it sends the required data when you have all the data, but if you have an error, the Profile is removed?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what it is.

Comment: It's likely an issue with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` - have you thought about just building the Profile model upon user signup & allowing / encouraging them to populate it on first login?

Comment: I did that as well, yes; the user is directed to the profile edit upon sign_up. The point is, no matter when they edit it, as long as there's an error, the profile is gone. I need the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to be able to access it from Devise or the Users controller, I wanna make all the edits in one form, or later in in-place editing.

Comment: You know what it might be - do you think Devise rebuilds the object each time it shows the form? Perhaps it could be removing the extra params you've set?

Comment: And how could I check and fix that? As mentioned, I am a real beginner, that's basically my experiment app after Hartl's tutorial.

Comment: Hmmmmm. I'd look at the Devise docs for adding extra params at User creation. I just saw something which is quite disturbing - you have `before_create :build_profile`

Comment: This would surely override your passed params? Have you tried disabling this?

Comment: based on numerous SO questions this was the way I found to create an automatic blank profile for a user upon signup.

Comment: Yes, it's the way I was suggesting :) But you're passing params to the profile? So if you're building a blank profile after create, that would override your `accepts_nested_attributes_for` call, no?

Comment: OK, so is there a work-around to take off the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and still be able to let devise handle the edit? I am looking into the docs now but no luck yet.

Comment: I'd take off the `build_profile` and see what happens ;)

Comment: What happens is that the profile doesn't get created. Also, I found out that it was like you said earlier, `accepts_nested_parameters_for` does create a a whole new profile object for the user, it doesn't update the existing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have setup Devise to allow users to edit their account without providing a password then you need to remove `current_password` field from the view as well as `configure_permitted_parameters` method.

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
...
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u| u.permit(
      :email, 
      :password, 
      :password_confirmation,
     ## :current_password,    ## REMOVE THIS LINE
      :name,
      profile_attributes: [:birthday, :phone, :address, :about, :restrictions, :avatar]
      ) 
  end
end
```

By specifying `current_password` you are permitting it for mass-assignment on `account_update`.

**UPDATE**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of :user
  before_create :build_profile # Creates profile at user creation
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  ...
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of :profile    
  validates :user_id, presence: true      
end
```

Comment: But I would still need this field if the user wanted to change the email or password.

Comment: So, is it like you don't want to provide current_password for updating other fields but want password for updating email or password?

Comment: I couldn't send messages there, I just started my SO account, that's basically my second contribution ever, so not enough reputation.

Comment: No Problem. Can you add the server log generated after the form submission, in the question. Also, do you mean that `user.profile becomes nil` upon form submission?

Comment: Can you also add the `update` action. I see `DELETE FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = ? ` in the log.

Comment: Well, it's just [Devise's own update action](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb). Now I noticed I would probably need to give a block, but I don't know where.

Comment: I am confused. In your question you said you followed `Devise Wiki` example which means that you have overridden `RegistrationsController#update` and now you are saying `it's just Devise's own update action`. Please clarify.

Comment: Ah, sorry I was confused with something. I added it to the question now. And changing the order didn't change anything.

Comment: I did that as @RichPeck mentioned as well, but then I lose the automatic build profile functionality. I think I'd solve the whole problem if I canceled the password requirement on everything.

Comment: I don't know the result of build_profile removal from before_create as you didn't share. Assuming that it did work then to resolve the automatic build profile functionality see my updated answer. Try it out.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was doing some reading about the subject. I tried the updated answer, but the build_profile method is built by the association and it's not available to this object, so it gives an "undefined" error.

Comment: Lets try my new Update.

Comment: It gives syntax errors. This is getting a little out of control :) and I'm beginning to feel stupid. I need to dig deeper. So far I discovered that the main reason is that it doesn't really update the profile, it creates a whole new one with new attributes. I literally followed [your and Rich's answers to that post and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976002/ruby-on-rails-4-devise-and-profile-pages); it works fine as long as I have a separate edit action and route, but not when i want to customize it for Devise. I'll see what else I could do. Thank you.