# Adding custom options for users in rails devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm attempting to add an option for users to choose to set their user.status to "Public" or "Private."  I have this working just fine in my form for users - it saves the status exactly as expected:

```
     <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :status, "Private or Public?" %>
      <%= f.select :status, options_for_select(user_statuses, @user.status) %>
     </div>
```

In application_helper.rb:

```
    def user_statuses
      [ ["Private", "Private"], ["Public", "Public"] ]
    end
```

However, if I add the same form group from above to my devise edit/new views, I can't get the status to save correctly.  The user's status remains unchanged/default.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You nailed it!  Thanks JKen, learned something new and that solved it.

Comment: Solved using the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459685/newly-added-columns-data-not-being-saved-to-db/23459815#23459815

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your tag contains ruby on rails 4, So I guess you are using rails4, the following answer is based on this guess.

There is a new feature strong parameter in rails 4, you have permit any parameter if you want to mass assignments.

In your case, if you want to save status as well, you have to permit it.

How to ?

In application_controller.rb

add code like

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected
    def configure_permitted_parameters
      if resource_class == User
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, 
          :password, :password_confirmation, :status) }
      end
    end
```

hope it helps, if not, please add more information about your app, so we can have further discussion.