# Ruby on rails : porfile creation with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, profiles

Am totally new to ruby on rails... I've followed this discussion --> [Ruby on Rails 4, Devise, and profile pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976002/ruby-on-rails-4-devise-and-profile-pages/21984487#21984487?newreg=7cb084db8b2d43dab536df4e1c199996). And i scaffolded profile, Yet got an error [click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLbs9.png)

any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like You don't have `user_id` attribute in Your `profiles_table`. Check again Your migration.

Comment: class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration<br/>
  def change<br/>
    create_table :profiles do |t|<br/>

      t.timestamps null: false<br/>
    end<br/>
  end<br/>
end -->this is profiles table and i don't have any user_id there what should i do??

Comment: Add `t.integer :user_id, null: false` to your migration, rollback previous one and you should be good.

BTW I think you should read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html 

You may also have other pending issues, but your associations are wrong for sure.